# module.exports gets undefined while importing on another file

Tags: node.js, requirejs, commonjs

This is my file structure for simple Express app.

```
server/
  |- models
  |--- users.js
  |- index.js
```

`index.js` is the entry point

```
const app = require('express')();
const Server = require('http').createServer(app)
const io = require('socket.io')(Server);
......
.....
.....
.....
....
module.exports = {
    Server,
    io
}
```

inside my `models/users.js` I need the `io` variable exported above just to emit some event to all connected clients if new user is added. for this I imported

```
const { io } = require('../index');
```

but `io` is `undefined`.
I have tried few other similar ways

```
const io = require('../index').io //
```

and

```
const io = require('../').io /index is useless on require
```

but none worked.
Am I being silly or did I miss something here.
any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Make sure `io` is not `undefined` in `index.js` itself. Try `console.log(io)` above `module.exports`

Comment: done that as well, `Server` and `io` before module.exports are defined .

Comment: Are you referencing `require('./models/users')` in your `index.js` anywhere?

Comment: Yes, he does, in line 10 (indirectly) [code: https://github.com/shankarregmi/basic-chat] and I wrote about it in my edited answer.

Answer (score 7):

This is an issue with:

## Importing in the right order

SlaWitDev was right about the line `const socketIOEvents = require('./socketIOEvents');` being a part of the issue.

This is a file that instantiates `users.js`. On instantiation of `users.js`, you are including the file you are *in the process of instantiating*. In other words, we haven't hit the bottom of the lines of code in `index.js`, for it to export the `io` object to that file.

`index.js` -> `socketIOEvents/index.js` -> `models/index.js`, -> `models/users.js`

### Checking the order

I've added a line of code to the top of these files to log when they get called, and then a line just before `module.exports` in the `index.js` file:

```
[nodemon] starting `node server`
index.js
socketIOEvents/index.js
models/index.js
models/users.js
Initializing routes
index.js module.exports assignment
Server is running on port 9000.
```

As you can see, `user.js` gets called **before** we export modules.

### Checking the imported object

As a result of the previous problem, if we add this line in `users.js`:

```
const test = require('../index');
console.log('test', test);
```

we get the output:

```
test {}
```

This means the object we imported doesn't have any keys, so performing object destructuring where you pull out the `io` key in:

```
const { io } = require('../index');
```

won't work.

### A solution:

If we move the `module.exports` lines and `const io` line in `index.js` to above socketIOEvents, you'll see that it starts to work:

```
...
const config = require('./config');

// start socket.io
const io = require('socket.io')(Server);

module.exports = {
  Server,
  io
};

const socketIOEvents = require('./socketIOEvents');
...
```

Note this is likely an *antipattern* and not a final solution, as module.exports is usually at the end of the file.

### Alternate solutions:

- Pass `io` into your model in socketIOEvents, the same way you pass it into your socketIOEvents file, by passing it as the argument into the function.
- Instance `io` in a separate file with Server being passed into it. Use this reference in both the main `index.js` file and the `users.js` file

Comment: I personally would recommend your first alternative solution. Dependency Injection makes everything clearer. Great answer overall.

Answer (score -1):

If you have node 6+ (ES6) this

```
const { io } = require('./../index');
```

should work.
Before go up in reqiure, get current directory first.

---

**Edit 1:**

**I've do some test with your code.**

I'm almost sure, it not work because, in this line (10) of `server/index.js`
`const socketIOEvents = require('./socketIOEvents');`
You require models [users.js]
but
const io is below (line 23).

---

in users.js comment line 9
and put file eg. test.js in modules folder with content:

```
// testing different import
const { io, Server } = require('./../index');
const io2 = require('./../index').io;
const io3 = require('./../').io

console.log('io', io); // working
console.log('io2', io2); // working
console.log('io3', io3); // working
```

---

And then **node server/models/test.js** and require('./../index') working

You just have trying to use variable before is exists.

Comment: It doesn't work as well. 
here is the code https://github.com/shankarregmi/basic-chat